# build ogre with emscripten

Tags: c++, ogre, emscripten

I have an Ogre project I'd like to port to the web with Emscripten.
To build Ogre there is a cmake command where I can specify Emscripten em++ as the compiler.
I generated the makefile.
Then I ran the command emmake make.
After many trials and errors, I generated a bytecode that I renamed with the .bc suffix and then ran

```
em++ project.bc -o project.html
```

I opened the html file in my web browser. The output is "-1" because there are many unresolved symbols (_ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv, etc...).

Has anyone managed to build Ogre with Emscripten? How?

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on Ogre Forums. Have a look at this: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=70671&p=501677&hilit=Emscripten#p501677 and this: https://github.com/joeyview/ogre/wiki/document

Comment: Did you mention the [Exported_Functions](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html?highlight=exported_functions) in the emcc command? If you do not do so, emscripten might remove functions from your js, while optimizing the generated code. 
So be sure that the make file has the correct exported functions.